# Why does np.select return 'nan' as a string instead of np.nan when np.nan is set as default value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am using `np.select` to create a new column based on multiple conditions applied to other columns. Here is a simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 3, 4], 'B': [10, 0, 2]})

mask1 = (df['A'] == 0)
mask2 = (df['A'] == 4)

df = df.assign(C = np.select([mask1, mask2], ['Cond1', 'Cond2'], default=np.nan))
```

Using `np.select` I am expecting that if neither of the conditions are met I should get an np.nan value in the `'C'` column, but when I look for NaNs in the dataframe using `df.isna().sum()` I don't get any.

I've tried looking this up but I cannot seem to find the answer. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out why: numpy arrays cannot contain multiple data types. Since I am filling column `C` with strings, numpy will insert the default value as `'nan'` instead of `np.nan` which is a float.

EDIT: a good workaround:

```
df = df.assign(C = pd.Series(np.select([mask1, mask2], ['Cond1', 'Cond2'], default=np.nan)).replace({'nan': np.nan}))
```

Comment: Pandas columns with strings are object dtype, and thus can c9ntain floats as well as python strings

Comment: `np.array(['cond1','cond2'], dtype=object)` might avoid this problem.

Answer (score 4):

It is worth knowing that pandas has it's own [arrays](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/arrays.html) (which are built on top of numpy arrays), but have a general missing values indicator `pd.NA` (note: it is still [experimental](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#experimental-na-scalar-to-denote-missing-values)).

So to make use of the pandas arrays, we can do:

```py
mask1 = (df['A'] == 0)
mask2 = (df['A'] == 4)

c = np.select([mask1, mask2], ['Cond1', 'Cond2'], default=pd.NA)
df = df.assign(C=c).convert_dtypes()
```

```
   A   B      C
0  0  10  Cond1
1  3   0   <NA>
2  4   2  Cond2
```

Then if we check the dtypes, we see that we are using the pandas arrays:

```
A     Int64
B     Int64
C    string
dtype: object
```